# How to 'evaluate' backspaces in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have `bytes`like `'foo\x20\x20\x08\x08bar'`

I need have the backspaces (`'\x08'`) evaluated when *and only when* they are lead by identical number of spaces (`'\x20'`).

`x = re.sub('\x20+\x08+', '', t)` is the naive way of doing this, but fails to produce correct output when `t = 'foo\x20\x20\x08'`

Is there a way to define a regular expression that takes the length of a previous group in to account when matching the second group or do I need do this manually with `re.finditer` & `re.span()` and then manually re-checking the preceding blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to pass a `lambda` to `re.sub`:

```
>>> pat ='(\x20+)(\x08+)' 
>>> repl = lambda m: m.group(1)[:-len(m.group(2))]
```

now:

```
>>> re.sub(pat, repl, 'foo\x20\x20\x08bar')
'foo bar'
>>> re.sub(pat, repl, 'foo\x20\x20\x08\x08bar')
'foobar'
>>> re.sub(pat, repl, 'foo\x20\x20\x08\x08\x08bar')
'foobar'
```

Comment: @vks see [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and the 2nd example there. The `repl` argument can be a function which receives a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) and returns a string.

Comment: that i know.I have  used it before.the use of lambda is somewhat confusing.Also when exactly the space has to be put?